# Select nth-child or nth-of-type that is wrapped in another element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="homepage-body">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="homepage-item">
        <div class="homepage-icon"></div>
        <div class="homepage-text">
            Test1
        </div>
    </div></a> <a href="#">
    <div class="homepage-item">
        <div class="homepage-icon"></div>
        <div class="homepage-text">
            Test2
        </div>
    </div></a> <a href="#">
    <div class="homepage-item">
        <div class="homepage-icon"></div>
        <div class="homepage-text">
           Test3
        </div>
    </div></a> <a href="#">
    <div class="homepage-item">
        <div class="homepage-icon"></div>
        <div class="homepage-text highlighted">
            Test4
        </div>
    </div></a>
</div>
```

I am trying to target each one of 4 `homepage-item` divs with different CSS. Instead of adding a separate class for each instance of `homepage-item` I am trying to utilize `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`.

I've tried different combinations of CSS, but the best it could do is to apply  the first (1) CSS to all four `homepage-item` divs:

```
.homepage-body > a > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: green;
}
.homepage-body > a > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: red;
}
.homepage-body > a > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: yellow;
}
.homepage-body > a > div:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Attach the `nth-of-type` selector to the `a`. Each `div.homepage-item` is the only element of its type under the `a`.

Comment: @Harry man, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this

```
.homepage-body > a:nth-of-type(1) > div {
  background: green;
}
```

---

*Side note:*

If you indent your code you will see this more clearly as well

```
<div class="homepage-body">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="homepage-item">
      <div class="homepage-icon"></div>
      <div class="homepage-text">
        Test1
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, few hours wasted and here I am getting an answer 1 min after posting. Thank you in particular and stackoverflow community in general! Will accept in 10 mins when allowed